# How to create table and post it on some remote server in Android using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

That is what I want my application to do. I found how to create table using:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + dbSubjectTable + " (" + dbSubjectId
            + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + dbSubjectName + "TEXT, "
            + dbSubscribed + "INTEGER, " + dbDate + "DATE);");  }
```

But I don't know how to send this table to the remote server.
**NOTE:** I don't want to send the whole database, but only a specific table (there are other tables also, i didn't specify for keeping question simple)

Answer (score 0):

Use Webservices, links [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/10/android-full-app-part-2-using-http-api.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) may help you.

Comment: not helping man, the link talks about sending database in general, not table as specific. I don't want to send the whole database only a specific table.

Comment: I imagine you will have to access your table, store it in a JSONObject and send it across to the Server, where a you can use either PHP, Java Servlet or any other language to again save in a Database. Does it sound like what you wish to do?

Comment: hmm, seems so....can you post your answer as answer rather than comment so that other people with similar request can find it easily...thnx